# Repeat last command with "sudo"

Tags: bash

I often forget to run commands with `sudo`. I'm looking for a way to make a bash function (or alias) for repeating the last command with `sudo`. Something like:

```
S() {
    sudo $(history 1)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Extra work needed for an alias: http://superuser.com/questions/240180/creating-an-alias-containing-bash-history-expansion

Comment: If you're not allergic to swearwords there is a package called `thefuck`: https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck. It tries to figure out any reason the previous command can't work and make it work (for example run with sudo). Just type `fuck`

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can write:

```
sudo !!
```

(See [§9.3 "History Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).)

Answer (score 26):

Not enough?

```
sudo !!
```

if you want the `S` simply put:

```
alias S=sudo
```

and use it

```
S !!
```

the `!!` mean the `last command`

Comment: Nice. My use was to instantly convert a delicately crafted command line into a script:
    `echo !! > script.sh`

Comment: Or `alias S='sudo $(history -p !!)'` then just type `S`

Answer (score 22):

Use `alias redo='sudo $(history -p !!)'`. This is the only thing that I 
have found that works with aliases. The other answers do not work in aliases for some reason, having tried them myself, even though they do work when directly running them.

Comment: for some reason I have to use eval `alias r='eval sudo $(history -p !!)'`

Answer (score 17):

`!!` can be used to reference the last command. So:

```
sudo !!
```

Answer (score 13):

Adding and expanding upon [Aaron Franke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4441547/aaron-franke)'s response (which is correct but lacking a *why*) such that simply typing `redo` works after configuring the alias `alias redo='sudo $(history -p !!)`;

> This is the only thing I found that works with aliases

There are a few things going on that warrant explanation.

```
alias redo='sudo !!'
```

doesn't work as it doesn't execute the `sudo` portion, though it does resolve the `!!`.

To get the `sudo !!` to resolve correctly, a shell resolution directive has to execute and concatenate along with `sudo`. So we do;

```
alias redo='sudo $(history -p !!)'
```

By specifying the right side of the alias to `$(history -p !!)`, what this does is say to the shell;

1. `redo` is an alias, assess the right side of the `=`
2. `sudo` remains as is and it concatenated to...
3. `$()` is a shell directive, to execute the contents within the current execution process (as oppose to a sub-shell `${}`, which spawns a different process to execute within)
4. Resolve `history -p !!`
5. The `!!` gets expanded to `history -p <lastCommandHere>` as a result of step 4.
6. The `-p` part says to `history` to only print the results, not execute
7. The `sudo`, executes the remaining (now printed out on the same command line), with elevated privileges, assuming password was entered correctly

This ultimately means that the command `history -p !!` effectively writes out the resolution rather than executing after the `sudo`.

**NOTE**: The `'` is significant. If you use `"`, the `!!` gets interpolated twice and to achieve our purpose we need to very carefully control the resolution steps; [single/double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781)

**PS**

If you're using `zsh` + `oh-my-zsh`, there is a `sudo` alias setup for `_` such that you can do;

```
_ !!
```

Which will rerun the last command as `sudo`. However, if you're configuring the alias in `~/.zshrc`, the `alias redo='sudo $(history -p !!)` will not work as is from the zsh config as the resolution steps are different.

That said, you can put the alias into `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.zshrc` and have the same result when executing the alias `redo` from zsh (assuming you're sub-shelling zsh from bash, though this is admittedly a bit of a kludge - though a functional one).

Comment: The tips for `zsh` are worth the price of admission :)