# How to rerun last command in zsh as sudo

Tags: zsh

I'm using `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`. I'm trying something very simple:

`alias fu='sudo !!'`

So, if I issued a command that needed a forgotten `sudo` I could quickly re-do it.

Yes, I googled for that and I even saw several [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245614) but **NONE** worked for me. For example:

```sh
ls
bla bla
!!
zsh: command not found: !!
```

I also tried:

```sh
ls
bla bla
fc -e : -1
bla bla
# that worked! But let's see with sudo...
ls
bla bla
sudo fc -e : -1
# nothing happens!
```

Another:

```sh
alias redo='sudo $(history -p !!)'
# didn't work
```

I've tried in Mac and Ubuntu, same issues.

Comment: History expansion is done before alias expansion. Hence, your `!!` doesn't get expanded.

Comment: I've read [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) and I can't find out why `!!` does not work on my `zsh` terminal. So the whole thing is why my first example is not working.

Comment: You have the `!!` inside an alias definition, and as you can see from the link you provided yourself, alias expansion comes later than history expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea (not tested), based on the link you provided in your question (but which explains a bash solution): Instead of an alias **redo**, you create a **function** of this name. Inside the function, you can do a

```
local last_hist=( $(fc -l -1) )
```

which stores the most recently executed command into the array `last_hist`, but prefixed by the history number. You remove the history number by

```
shift last_hist
```

and execute your sudo command by

```
sudo "${last_hist[@]}"
```

However, is it so much more work to just write

```
sudo !!
```

instead of your carefully crafted function

```
redo
```

?

Comment: Your suggestion is a good start, I did this in order to get it working:
`function fu { local last_hist=( $(fc -l -1) ); shift last_hist; doit="sudo $last_hist"; echo "$doit"; eval $doit }`

Comment: I don't understand why `eval` would be needed in this case.

Comment: So it can handle commands like `ls -l P10*`, where `*` has to be interpreted correctly.

Comment: I found the reason for while `!!` is not working in my `zsh`.

The complete explanation is [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html).

My `.zshrc` had a line `unsetopt BANG_HIST` so to keep compatibility with legacy `ksh` scripts where I used to work. I probably got this from someone there and failed to comment on it. Removing it and `!!` does work now.

But in the end, the best solution I found was cited in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245614/repeat-last-command-with-sudo) and it's [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck).